# An overview of jquery.ajax and making a request to the server

Tags: jquery

OK perhaps I have read too many posts on this subject and now I am confused.

Can someone please give a brief overview of the process to follow in order to make an ajax request in Jquery and pick up the results of the call.

I suppose question 1 is would you elect to use jquery over javscript to make the xhr request?

I can see perfectly well how the javascript approach works, it make sense and is easy to follow. But various articles point to the benefit of using jquery claiming that

("#input_Field1").load("ajax_Request.php"); is all you need to make the asynchronous call.

If this is the case what are you supposed to do with jquery.ajax together with its settings and global event handlers and how does this impact on the .load

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery simplifies the JavaScript to make XHR requests, generally an AJAX request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    data: 'data=test',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Here you post the variable 'data' with value 'test' to 'page.php', the callback function success() is then called and you can do something with whatever data page.php returns.

$.load() is somewhat different in that you can simply say:

```
$('#container').load('test.php');
```

And the contents of 'test.php' will be placed into the element with the ID of 'container'. So here the answer to your question is yes, that's all you need to make an AJAX request.

Check out the [$.load() event handlers and variables here](http://api.jquery.com/load/), and the [$.ajax ones here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Hi Tom, Thank goodness for that clarification. I thought that this may be the case but could not find this stated anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: The other point that I cannot decide upon is whether it is better i.e. is it more efficient or best practice to construct HTML to pass back from the server side or is it best to pass data back as XML and use for example use SimpleXML to do the required manipulations on the client side. Is there an accepted view? From my reading to date the later appears to fit a 'proper' approach to ajax. However the former seems much neater.

Comment: It depends what you're passing back, if you are updating your UI based on the request I'd go with simply passing back constructed HTML as this would be neater, but if you want to decide what to do on the client side once the request completes you may want to look into returning data in a format such as JSON. Also feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Hi Tom, ok that makes perfect sense - again it may appear obvious to others who have experience in this area. But I wasn't sure if there was some hidden consequence of choosing one over the other. Especially as this doesn't appear to be stated anywhere. Thank you so much for your help. You have made all that reading fall into place.

Comment: No worries, after all that's what SO is here for!